# What's the difference between 2 lines in PHP?

Tags: php, jqgrid

I have found in jqGrid server side PHP example next line

```
$start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
```

What's the difference between

```
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;
```

and

```
$start = $limit*($page - 1);
```

Why do authors not recommend the second way ?

Comment: The difference is `$limit` is factored out in the second method, but `$start` should still be the same in both cases.

Comment: It gives the same result. Weird.

Comment: @gion_13, I wouldn't say it's weird, because the second "unrecommended" form is simply a factored version of the "recommended" form. What is strange, however, is why the comment in the code would recommend one way over the other.

Comment: It's just a difference between parens in math vs parens in programming. With our math brains on, we see that they are the same... but with our programming brains, we see that it's not associative multiplication, it actually resolves the inside of the parens first, then multiplies.

Comment: Or perhaps I'm overanalyzing (it's late...). I think they are the same :-/

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, both expressions should yield the same result.
**Practically**, because of floating point arithmetics in the CPU (assuming we are not considering integers exclusively), there might be a big difference in the result of those two expressions.

**Example:**
imagine `$page` is a really BIG number.
In that case, `1` in the expression `$page - 1` would be factored out (because 1 is smaller by several orders of magnitude than `$page`),
and the expression `$start = $limit*($page - 1);` would be equivalent to `$start = $limit*$page;`
In the first way, we don't have such a problem, and that's why it's recommended.

**Conclusion:**
Mathematically, it makes no difference.
Practically, the CPU (the floating point arithmetic unit) can handle only limited orders of magnitude, and smaller numbers oftentimes get factored out when combined with big numbers.

**Edit:**
An example is worth a 1000 words...
Take a look at this fiddle and see how two *mathematically* identical expressions yield different results:
http://jsfiddle.net/EyalAr/Z9BT5/

Comment: Wise answer. BUT `$limit*($page - 1);` (the unrecommended way) is more precise than the recommended way.

Comment: You forgot to explain, why `$page - 1` is so much worse than `($limit * $page) - ($limit * 1)`. I don't see any change in the difference of order of magnitude between those two operations.

Comment: @Wormbo: rody_o already added the explanation to this as answer.

Comment: for all those who wondered if there's an actual difference, take a look at the link in the edit of my answer.

Comment: In context it'd be strange if `$page` or `$limit` were anything other than integers.

Comment: perhaps, but the context of the problem is irrelevant to the issue of floating point arithmetic...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a numerical math issue. Suppose `$page` is huge, as in `6.02e231`. Then

```
($page - 1) = 6.02e231
```

(the exact same floating point representation), so that

```
$limit*($page - 1) = $limit*$page
```

From the point of view of any processor. Compare

```
$limit*$page = [SOME HUGE VALUE]
$limit*$page - $limit = [SUBTRACTION OF TWO HUGE VALUES]
```

which will yield a *different* result, more accurate than the "minus one" notation.

So although in the perfect world of mathematics, the two notations are equal, in the non-perfect world of computing, the first one is more prone to 'catastrophic cancellation' (wiki that) than the second.

Comment: If you have a grid with this many rows, I think precision of the paging calculation is the least of your problems. 6e231 is many orders of magnitude more than the number of atoms in the universe, so there's no database that can store all that data.

Comment: @Barmar: the above was only an example; there are more ways in which the two calculations can lead to different results, even though they are mathematically equivalent. And trust me, if you don't take care of this sort of thing, it will come back three years later to bite you in the butt!

Comment: It's not "just an example". The comment appears in all the sample code on the jqGrid site. That exact line, including the comment, appears in all the sample code on the jqGrid site. They don't have to worry about the general case. While the programmer might have a preference for this style, that doesn't explain why he felt it necessary to put a comment recommending against the equivalent.

Comment: @Barmar: Your argument is not actually countering my previous argument, but oh well. True, in this particular case it shouldn't really matter, given that *in practice* it only concerns integers within a range where you need not care. I'm no expert here, but they could for instance have a testing framework that checks the validity of things for the complete range of 64-bit integers or something. I'd say it's at least *good habit* to go for the more "stable style", everywhere. That way, you never "stop thinking", and whenever floating point calculations come along, there will be less surprises.

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;
```

This will first perform multiply operation then minus the limit to result

```
$start = $limit*($page - 1);
```

This will first minus the $page by 1 then multiple with $limit

Comment: This is BODMAS precedence, what is the issue @Hossein ?

Comment: You didn't answer his question. Both forms will evaluate to the same value. He wants to know why the second form is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in algebra, multiplication happens before addition/subtraction in the order of operations. See [PHP's precedence documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). So the first line does $limit * $page, and then subtracts limit, which is actually the same as `$page * ($limit-1)`.

I think the reason to hint away from that, is that in algebra the statements are mathematically the same, but in programming they are not (parens are taken as order-of-operation indicators instead of a quantity representation)

Comment: Looking at it mathematically, take `$limit*($page - 1)` and use the distributive property (multiplication distributes over addition) and you can make it `$limit*$page - $limit`. That's what I mean by mathematically the same.

Comment: Indeed, `4 * 1 - 4 = 4 - 4 = 0`.

Comment: Yup, I got that junk outta there. Sorry folks. I'll go to bed now.

Answer (score 0):

The second method is not suggested normally because in the older languages/compilers, the second statement results in `-0`. The `-0` creates some other problem in calculations and hence, the first method is preferred.

You can see the above being executed here: [Code in PHP(No `-0` observed)](http://codepad.org/rD7ztA2Y) and [Code in Lua(Observe `-0` in output)](http://codepad.org/DGj10TK1)

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. He's not going to echo $start, he'll use it in further calculation.

Comment: @Hossein As I said, in PHP, there is no problem. But the books don't mention the second result because the reason stated above.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't see why the second version would not be recommended.

```
$c = $a * $b - $a;
```

In an abstract view, this would be calculated as follows:

1. Load `$a` into CPU register 1.
2. Load `$b` into CPU register 2.
3. Multiply both registers, storing the result into register 2.
4. `$a` is still in register 1. Subtract it from register 2, storing the result in either of the registers.
5. Save result register to `$c`.

Provided the compiler sees that both `$a` operands in the equation are identical, that entire line would use only two CPU registers.

```
$c = $a * ($b - 1);
```

1. Load `$a` into register 1. This should be done first, because PHP guarantees order of evaluation from left to right, as far as I remember.
2. Load `$b` into register 2.
3. Decrement register 2. This is a separate operation, so the `1` does not need to be loaded explicitly.
4. Multiply registers 1 and 2, storing the result in either of them.
5. Save result register to `$c`.

That looks pretty much like the same effort to me. Then again, they might have profiled the entire thing and found that for some reason (for example due to the context of the line) the first version is more efficient.

Assuming integer arithmetics, there is absolutely no difference in the result. I also don't quite share the floating point arguments, because if `$page` is such a large number, it still won't really matter which version you use. Either you subtract `1` from a very large number, showing no effect. Or you multiply the large number and the `1` separately by the same factor and then perform subtraction. The two values will have the same difference in orders of magnitude as the originals, `$page` and `1`.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought about the speed reason, but it seems that the second version is even a lil bit faster: [speed test](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FvKVQp)

Answer (score -1):

**The programmer was being over-careful about accuracy.**

There is no difference at all mathematically.

From programmers point of view, the operator precedence does not matter since the variables are basic numbers. (If they were instances of the foo classe with overloaded operator, the story was different)

There is a possible lose of accuracy in the `$limit*$page - $limit` form, see rody_o's answer on this. But that won't happen since I don't ever think $page and $limit are of an order of magnitude of 10^38 or something. But php knows how to handle numbers. And remember, we don't even know they are floats!

As others also mentioned execution speed, this is not something the programmer may have had in mind. Do you really care about writing which form in your code? Choosing one form over the another is not even a micro-optimization.

There is no reason to tell others they should absolutely NOT use the second form. It's just okay.